# Use my application for NFC payment when not set as default

Tags: android, nfc, android-pay

Hi I'm working on android application for NFC payments.

There is an option in Android settings to use an open application instead of the default one. For example when I have default application set to Android Pay and I open my app before the payment - I want to use my app for the payment instead of the default one. See image bellow.

[image]

I tested it, but unfortunately I paid with Android Pay instead of my app that was running in foreground.

I did not find any word in documentation, if I have to add something to manifest, register something etc..?

I have `service` with `intent filter` and `meta data` in my manifest and when the app is set as default for payment, it is working correctly:

```
<service
        android:name="com.example.MyWalletHceService"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NFC_SERVICE">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.cardemulation.action.HOST_APDU_SERVICE"/>
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.nfc.cardemulation.host_apdu_service"
            android:resource="@xml/apduservice"/>
    </service>
```

Adding apduservice xml content:

```
<host-apdu-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:apduServiceBanner="@drawable/ic_logo_nfc_system"
               android:description="@string/nfc_service_title"
               android:requireDeviceUnlock="false">

<aid-group
    android:category="payment"
    android:description="@string/nfc_aid_desc">
    <!-- Following is a PPSE AID. You must always include this AID in order for payments to
         work-->
    <aid-filter android:name="@string/aid_number"/>
    <!-- Following AID list is specific to the application requirements.
       If your application supports the type of card that these AID represents,
       you must include those AID in your configuration file -->
    <aid-filter android:name="@string/aid_mc_filter"/> <!-- Mastercard DEBIT/CREDIT -->
</aid-group>
```

Comment: What's the contents of the apduservice XML file?

Comment: @MichaelRoland I updated my question with apdu XML content.

Comment: All those string definitions exist, right? What's the value of those `aid_*`strings? And, your app does show up as a choice for setting the default payment app in the Tap & pay settings, right?

Comment: @Sandak Is there documentation to integrate with the contactless NFC payment feature?

Comment: @StepanSanda, could you share any simple guide/wiki for a basic NFC payments?
I'm looking to develop a "wallet" for NFC payment and can't find simple naive examples.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So I finally found a solution!

You have to use [setPreferredService(Activity, ComponentName)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/cardemulation/CardEmulation.html#setPreferredService(android.app.Activity,%20android.content.ComponentName)) in your current foreground activity. It is recommended to to call it inside `onResume()` and also do not forget to call [unsetPreferredService(Activity)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/cardemulation/CardEmulation.html#unsetPreferredService(android.app.Activity)) once the activity is not in foreground (`onPause()` is good place to call it).

One more thing: 
[setPreferredService(Activity, ComponentName)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/cardemulation/CardEmulation.html#setPreferredService(android.app.Activity,%20android.content.ComponentName)) and [unsetPreferredService(Activity)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/cardemulation/CardEmulation.html#unsetPreferredService(android.app.Activity)) were added in API 21, so be sure not to call them from older API.